# Difference in behaviour of sql query in oracle11g two releases

Tags: oracle11g

We have two database one with version 11.2.0.1.0 and othe with 11.2.0.3.0

Query

```
SELECT * 
  from chn_chr 
 where Chn_CRTN_DT < '08-Aug-2012 02.20.30.000000 PM'
```

is not working with release 11.2.0.3.0,but the same query is working with release 11.2.0.1.0.

I have verified all the NLS parameters(session,instance,database) and its same for both the releases.

Is this the probleme with release or something else I need to check?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  Is there some reason that you need to rely on implicit data type conversion rather than using an explicit `TO_DATE` or `TO_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: When I am running this query from sql developer I am getting ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string", But the same query I have tried to run from Unix box and I got the expected output.

Comment: Then you need to check the difference in nls settings between sql developer and the database session on the unix box.

Comment: Is there some reason that you need to rely on implicit data type conversion rather than using an explicit `TO_DATE` or `TO_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Yes SQL Developer has NLS settings of its own that you have to consider. As Justin implies, it's not a good idea to rely on implicit data conversion.